# mailto + multiple adresses doesn't work with mobile chrome?

Tags: mailto

http://fbnydob.applinzi.com/mailceshi.php?e=test@example.com+example@test.com

```
<?php
    if (!sizeof($_GET)){   
                        //some code                   
    } else { ?>

  <html>
  <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


      </head>
      <body style="margin:0;padding:0">
    The mail is going to be sent to
      <br>

      <div id="email" style="width:100vw;">

    </div>

  </body>
  <script>
    query = location.search;
    query = query.replace(/\+/g,',');
    query = query.replace('?e=','');
    show = query.replace(/,/g,', ');
    document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = show;

          location.href = "mailto:" + query;

  </script>
  </html>

<?php } ?>
```

A very simple page to send emails based on URL parameters. The strange thing is, if I open this on Mac or desktop chrome, it will open the Mail program; However, in mobile chrome, it doesn't work. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: maybe use a `,` instead of `+`? `+` in urls maps to a space, and that space may not be treated as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

The `mailto` URI scheme has changed over time.  [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) (1998) specifies just a single address; [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) (2010), which obsoletes 2368, permits multiple comma-separated destinations.  It's likely that the problematic user agent implements only the former specification.

Not only that, but you're using the wrong separator:

> *to* = *addr-spec* *("`,`" *addr-spec* )